# How to communicate between to webApi .net core

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I'm very new to .net, I want to create a new webAPI with .net core. One of my requirements is to pull up some data from other existing .net webAPI. My question is:

Which the best way to address the communication between the apis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the existing web API is outside of your C# / Visual Studio project, then just call via an http request. You can use the `HttpClient` class to create a request. Your code should look similar to this

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));


 var result = client.GetStringAsync("http://url-of-your-existing-api");

 var json = await result;
 // deserialize your json here ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can learn how to use message broker such as `RabbitMQ` see the [link to RabbitMQ here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/)

> RabbitMQ is lightweight and easy to deploy on premises and in the cloud. It supports multiple messaging protocols. RabbitMQ can be deployed in distributed and federated configurations to meet high-scale, high-availability requirements.
>
> RabbitMQ runs on many operating systems and cloud environments, and provides a wide range of developer tools for most popular languages.